# Rails + find_by_sql: how to select collections where its products count is more than 15?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to practice SQL, and this is more for console use not in my actual model. I have a `Collection` model that `has_many: products`. I want to do a search for all the collections that have more than 15 products.

This is what I have written (and is wrong):

`Collection.find_by_sql("SELECT c.id FROM collections c WHERE count(product_id) > 15")`

Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM services WHERE collection_id = c.id) services_count
FROM collections c WHERE services_count > 15
```

Can you try this?, I have not tested it.

Also, there is a way to do this without plain SQL, using Active Record, but I don't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this sql query will help you

```
select collections.*, count(products.id) as count_products from collections
inner join products on products.collection_id = collections.id
having count_products > 15
```